# LinkedIn oauth 2.0 (REST) with Ionic framework on Apple Device

Tags: angularjs, linkedin-api, ionic-framework

I'm trying to retrieve a LinkedIn users profile information by authenticating them on my hybrid application.

I have tried to use the REST api, but I can not register a redirect URL on LinkedIn in order for this to work.

From:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

I used:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code
&client_id=YOUR_API_KEY
&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress
&state=STATE
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
```

... but because applications on an iPhone get's installed with a unique URL, I cannot register it on LinkedIn as a redirect URL.

I also tried using the javascript API, but can not load the page dynamically for the button to appear and parse correctly.

From: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial

Is there anyone that found a different solution to implement this on Ionic or any other Hybrid application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm currently working on the same thing and ran into similar issues. My approach is to use the InAppBrowser for the user login to LinkedIn and then grab the authcode from that response. Then, send the authcode to my node backend, where I issue a request with it and my client secret to get the access token.

Here are a few resources for oAuth with phonegap that I found very useful:

[Using An Oauth 2.0 Service With IonicFramework](http://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/using-oauth-2-0-service-ionicframework/)

[Ionic forums - OAuth Login](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/oauth-login/4399)

(would have left this as a comment, but can't due to my reputation)

Comment: additional link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/oauth2-with-intelxdk-cordova-html5#o2a

Comment: Thank you. Very useful. I was under the impression that redirect URLs had to be valid.

Comment: First link is dead.